# Integrar funcion input PHP en input HTML

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Buenas, estoy tratando de integrar una función PHP en un input HTML, ya que si quito el input HTML y dejo solo la función PHP, al no coger los estilos el campo se reduce de ancho a la mitad, como podéis observar en la imagen.*

#### PHP + HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Username</label> 
    <?php echo form_input($identity); ?>
    <!-- <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Usuario..." class="form-username form-control" id="form-username">-->
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que el form_input() de codeigniter por defecto retorna con style="50%" lo que hace que tu input quede a la mitad. pero podes modificar eso en el array que le pasas al form_input() utilizando el campo "style", te dejo un ejemplo.

```
$identity = array('nombre' => 'jhon', 'apellido' => 'doe', 'style' => 'width:100%;')
```

Tambien tenes la posibilidad de agregar clases css con el campo 'class'.

Answer (score 1):

asumo que `$identity` es el html de tu nuevo campo, por favor muestranos como lo construyes y agregale las clases css tal cual las tienes en tu input HTML, este deberia verse automaticamente como los inputs q ya manejas.